# Using JavaScript code behind asp.net core c#

Tags: asp.net-core

I want to use sweet alert with asp.net core c#. To replace my alert system. However I need some guidance.
When I am on a controller say edit and just after the save I want to excute this javascript what is my best way in .net core in web forms days we had registerscript.

I also need to show this message when I create a record

https://sweetalert2.github.io/

```
swal({
        title: "MIS",
        text: "Case Created your Case Number is ",
        icon: "warning",
        buttons: true,
        dangerMode: true,
    })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to use AJAX on my .NETCORE 3.1 application to implement the Sweet Alert 2.

The syntax is just a little different than yours.

Documentation for Sweet Alert 2 can be found [on this link.](https://sweetalert2.github.io/#download)

A simple example, say you want an early on a button click, you could do something like:

HTML:

```
<input id="btnSubmit" type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-block" value="Submit" />
```

jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#btnSubmit").click(function () {
            Swal.fire({
                title: 'MIS',
                text: "Case Created your Case Number is",
                icon: 'error',
                confirmButtonText: 'Ok'
           })
        });
    });
</script>
```

Also, don't forget to add your sweetalert script tags:

```
<script src="~/filepath/sweetalert2.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: that will not get the value of the case created Renna answer was more complete

Answer (score 3):

**1.If you want to alert after save successfully,follow this:**

*Model:*

```
public class Test
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

*Index.cshtml:*

```
@model IEnumerable<Test>
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
            </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
                </td>
                <td>
                    <a asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Edit</a> |
                    <a asp-action="Details" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Details</a> |
                    <a asp-action="Delete" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Delete</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
@section Scripts
{
    @if (TempData["notification"] != null)
    {
        @Html.Raw(TempData["notification"])
    }
}
```

*Edit.cshtml:*

```
@model Test
<h4>Test</h4>
<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="Edit">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <input type="hidden" asp-for="Id" />
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Name" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Name" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Name" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    <a asp-action="Index">Back to List</a>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
}
```

*Controller:*

```
public class TestsController : Controller
{
    private readonly Mvc3_1Context _context;

    public TestsController(Mvc3_1Context context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public void Alert(int id)
    {
        var msg = "<script language='javascript'>swal({title: 'MIS',text: 'Case Created your Case Number is "+id+"', icon: 'warning',buttons: true,dangerMode: true})" + "</script>";
        TempData["notification"] = msg;
    }

    // GET: Tests
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {
        return View(await _context.Test.ToListAsync());
    }
    // GET: Tests/Edit/5
    public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        var test = await _context.Test.FindAsync(id);
        if (test == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        return View(test);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int id, Test test)
    {
        if (id != test.Id)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            _context.Update(test);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync(); 

            Alert(id);//add this method

            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }
        return View(test);
    }
}
```

*_Layout.cshtml:*

```
<script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/js/site.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>

//add this line
<script src="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
```

*Result:*
[image]

---

**2.If you want to alert before save sucessfully:**

*Model:*

Same as the option one.

*Index.cshtml:*

```
@model IEnumerable<Test>
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
            </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
                </td>
                <td>
                    <a asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Edit</a> |
                    <a asp-action="Details" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Details</a> |
                    <a asp-action="Delete" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Delete</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

*Edit.cshtml:*

```
@model Test
<h4>Test</h4>
<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form>
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <input type="hidden" asp-for="Id" />
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Name" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Name" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Name" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="button" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="confirmEdit()"/>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    <a asp-action="Index">Back to List</a>
</div>

@section Scripts {
<script>
    function confirmEdit() {
        swal({
            title: "MIS",
            text: "Case Created your Case Number is " + $("#Id").val(),
            icon: "warning",
            buttons: true,
            dangerMode: true,
        }).then((willUpdate) => {
            if (willUpdate) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "/tests/edit/"+$("#Id").val(),
                    type: "POST",
                    data: {
                        Id: $("#Id").val(),
                        Name:$("#Name").val()
                    },
                    dataType: "html",
                    success: function () {
                        swal("Done!", "It was succesfully edited!", "success")
                            .then((success) => {
                                window.location.href="/tests/index"
                            });
                        
                    },
                    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                        swal("Error updating!", "Please try again", "error");
                    }
                });
            }
        });                       
    }
</script>
}
```

*Controller:*

```
    public class TestsController : Controller
{
    private readonly Mvc3_1Context _context;

    public TestsController(Mvc3_1Context context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }
    // GET: Tests
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {
        return View(await _context.Test.ToListAsync());
    }
    // GET: Tests/Edit/5
    public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        var test = await _context.Test.FindAsync(id);
        if (test == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        return View(test);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int id, [FromForm]Test test)
    {
        if (id != test.Id)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            _context.Update(test);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();              
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }
        return View(test);
    }
}
```

*_Layout.cshtml:*

Same as option one.

*Result:*
[image]

Comment: Thanks for taking the time apreciate it

Comment: How would one achieve this for the create command as well the intial save?

Comment: Hi @rogue39nin,did you want to apply sweet alert to create action?Which option is your requirement?

Comment: Hi Rena both is my requirment i will updated the question

Comment: As you see the answer is too long.Please post a new thread and share your sample.

Comment: I ask the question here 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62813249/triggering-sweet-alert-message-from-the-code-behind-for-create-method